# in CSV file. I would like to extract several values using df.loc and apply the calculation formula to each of these values using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in CSV file. I would like to extract several values using df.loc and apply the calculation formula to each of these values.

```
try:
    args = sys.argv
    curdir = os.path.dirname(args[0])



    for path in glob.glob(curdir + '/output/*.csv'):
        f = open(path, 'r')
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        # print(df)
        time1 = df.loc[:, 'TIME']
```

There are several values and I want to apply the formula below to each of these values.
The formula I want to apply is this. = (value/86400) + 25569

ex) Sample example

```
        TIME       count
0    1645662056  2484200580
1    1645662057  2484218640
```

Comment: Please provide a sample (first few lines, or all relevant lines) of the .csv file you're processing, or a similar example.

Comment: I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ 1645662056, 1645662057], columns = ['time'])    
df = df.assign(count = lambda x: ((x['time'] /86400) + 25569) )
```

Output I get:

```
    time    count
0   1645662056  44616.014537
1   1645662057  44616.014549
```

Comment: There's no change
Don't you need to specify time1 separately? sorry  
Execution code
        df2 = df.assign(count = lambda x: ((x['TIME'] /86400) + 25569) )
        print(df2)

Comment: I have edited it :)

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([ 1645662056, 1645662057], columns = ['time'])

It's hard to specify because there are thousands of prices, is there any other way? I'm sorry.

Comment: Ues this as this is your data source: for path in glob.glob(curdir + '/output/*.csv'):
        f = open(path, 'r')
        df = pd.read_csv(f)  df = df.assign(count = lambda x: ((x['time'] /86400) + 25569) )

Comment: It's weird. It hasn't changed  
    for path in glob.glob(curdir + '/output/*.csv'):
        f = open(path, 'r')
        df = pd.read_csv(f)

        df = df.assign(count = lambda x: ((x['TIME'] /86400) + 25569) )

        print(df)

Comment: Sorry, What output you get?

Comment: This code resolved.
for path in glob.glob(curdir + '/output/*.csv'):
f = open(path, 'r')
df = pd.read_csv(f)
def plus(x):
y = (x/86400)+25569
return y
df1 = df['TIME'].apply(plus)
print(df1)
Thank you!